# Do working residuals mean anything in GLM

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, residuals

In R, the residuals attribute of a generalized linear model fit is not the deviance residuals but the working residuals, which I guess are a product of the iterative scheme to perform maximum likelihood estimation. Are these residuals relevant to checking the model? Are they important to understand?